# Closure - library not loading properly

Tags: javascript, loading, require, google-closure

I've got a Closure environment running fine in my development environment. In a new folder & file, however, it is not working.

For example, take this test script:

```
goog.require('goog.dom');
console.log(goog);
console.log(goog.dom);
goog.dom.getElement('logout').innerHTML = "Heck";
```

That's all, plus the `base.js` in the HTML.

The first `console.log` shows an object with all the right stuff is in there. All the files are loaded into the DOM too.

The second console log, however, says `undefined` and so the last line doesn't work (obviously). The Chrome console error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElement' of undefined`.

What the heck is going on?  It's the same if I try `XhrIo`. It's not finding the methods on the `goog` object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation:](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted)

> Note: Do not put your goog.require() statements in the same script tag
>   as the entry point to code that uses the goog.required functions or
>   classes. A goog.require() call adds code to the document **after** the
>   script tag containing the call.

So

```
<script>
    goog.require('goog.dom');
    console.log(goog.dom);
</script>
```

prints `undefined`. But

```
<script>
    goog.require('goog.dom');
</script>
<script>
    console.log(goog.dom);
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    goog.require('goog.dom');
    addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log(goog.dom);
    });
</script>
```

prints an Object.

FYI, there are other possible workflows. For example, the closurebuilder.py script can help to load all the required files ahead of time.